# Wait for previous axios response to complete before sending next request

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm building a react-redux app. When the app starts it sends the server a login request, to which the server replies with some authentication information. After retrieving the authentication data, the app should send another request for fetching data. I'm currently having something like this for my `thunk`s that execute those actions:

```js
const login = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.get('/login/').then(res => {
        // The user doesn't have to provide their username in this case. The backend handles 
        //  authentication for us automatically and sends back the auth data
        let {username, staff_id, first_name, last_name, groups} = res.data
        dispatch(auth(username, staff_id, first_name, last_name, groups))
    }) // save authentication info to redux state
}

const fetchData= () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    let myUsername = getState().auth.username
    axios.get(`/staff/${myUsername}`).then(res => {
       // stuff
    })
}
```

For the code to work, I have to wait for the axios response to complete in `login` before running `fetchData`, since `fetchData` needs the authentication data to work. I also don't want to dispatch `fetchData` in `login`, but instead call it in my component, something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.login()
        // how do I dispatch fetchData here?
    }

    render() {
         // stuff
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can make the axios calls sequential?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in your auth reducer after LOGIN_SUCCESS type or something you can say is_Authenticated: true, so in the App component you can see whether current user did login.

Reducer example:

```
import {LOGIN_SUCCESS} from '../types'  
const authState = {
    isAuthenticated: false
}

export default (state=authState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
            }
        ...
        default:
            return state
```

App component example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {fetchData} from './actions' // actions route
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        is_Authenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    componentDidMount = () => { 
        if(this.props.is_Authenticated){
            this.props.fetchData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already thought of that, but that doesn't answer the question of how do I call fetchData in my App component?

Comment: The problem with this is (I think) that componentDidMount is only called once. So, if I'm not authenticated, then the condition is false and fetchData is not run. Instead, I have to somehow watch the state and dispatch fetchData whenever isAuthenticated changes, which is what I'm currently struggling with.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/mr0b0t0/basic-authorization . It is very simple. In two words, the very first thing that is done here is loading a user by checking a token which is being stored after login action